# How to start an application at a given time in dos command line?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dos, command-prompt

I read on google about a month back that there is a command in dos, That performs a task at a particular time.

for example. 
You can turn on your notepad at a particular time and date.You can run your desired application at a specific date and time.But unfortunately I did not concetrate more on it I read the basics and left it off.Now I have been googling it from 2 days I dont find it.Does any one gone through it.

Does anyone knows a site regarding these or atleast a few commands to me to go through. please let me know it Because I want that command in one of my c project.So guys please help me.

And please if you have time then post more and more answers so that i could get more and more information to work on.I would accept the one that made me more sense. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `schtasks`

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 30 /tn "Task runs Every 30 Minuts" /tr c:\PATH\TO\TASK.exe
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_minutes

If you are on an archaic operating system, where schtasks is not available, use `at`:

```
at 00:00 cmd /c copy C:\Documents\*.* C:\MyDocs
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565/en-us